# Google Spreadsheet - how to modify image that has assigned script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

Everywhere I've read, it says to create a "button" in Google Spreadsheet you need to insert an image and assign a script to it. Easy enough. Done.

Now how do I modify that image? Clicking on the image runs the script. I cannot right-click the image for any context menu. I cannot select the image in any other way. I cannot ever remove the image now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you can "assign a script" to an image, you can also do so to a drawing - which is much easier to customize. Either way, you end up with a picture in the spreadsheet, and when you click on it a script is triggered.

To edit this behavior, just right-click the image or drawing. (I know you said you did this, but it DOES work. Just click - then let go.) An anchor will appear on the image or drawing, and from there you can access a menu to edit or delete the image or change the attached script.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: But like you noted, as i said it didn't work for me. Turned out it was specific to the version of Firefox i had at home. It worked in Firefox at work, but not at home. Worked fine in Chrome and other browsers too. Thanks though

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps Slav was using a Mac when he tried it the first time. Strangely, in this specific scenario, the Mac equivalent of right-clicking (which is CTRL+click) really does *not* work. What works is CMD + click.

Answer (score 0):

So that was tricky to me because the anchor was invisible in my image; it had a black background. If you can't see the anchor on your image follow these steps:

- Right click on the image, You should find that it now has resize handles
- Move your cursor to the top right of the image until it changes to a hand that points with the index finger (like when you hover over a link)
- Click
- Do whatever you want (Edit, delete... etc.)